# FormValidation in 2 submit buttons

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have 2 submit buttons 'update and 'exit', how to determine if the 'exit' was clicked and if it's clicked then disable the FormValidation?

please help

thanks
FD

Answer (score 0):

You can use different ajax call for each submit bottom, and do whatever you want on their own function.

Answer (score 0):

For Javascript you can use this:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="functionToDoOnTheClick">Submit</button>
```

This is what your HTML should look like on your submit button then in your javascript you can have the function which will disable your form validation. The name of that function you want to add into the quotes for onlick"".